# Ball bounce off the walls in C++ using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create a simple animation of a ball that is wandering on a screen and simply bounces off on walls. Since I'm fairly new to C++, I've got some problems with this task. I'm also using the Qt-library. 
The ball just stays on the same spot and moves back and forth a little which is odd, because I create a SceneRect with the same size as my graphicsView.

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QtWidgets>


float movement_x = 2.5;
float movement_y = 2.0;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void MainWindow::showEvent(QShowEvent *event){


    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);

    scene -> setSceneRect(ui->graphicsView->geometry().x(),          ui->graphicsView->geometry().y(),
                      ui->graphicsView->geometry().width(), ui->graphicsView->geometry().height());
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    QPen redpen(Qt::red);


    QBrush brush(Qt::green);
    //QBrush brush2(Qt::black);
    QPen mypen(Qt::blue);
    mypen.setWidth(7);


     ellipse = scene->addEllipse(100.0,100.0,20.0,20.0,mypen,brush);
     timer1 = startTimer(50);
     timer2 = startTimer(600);

}

void MainWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event){
    // check for radius
    if(ellipse->pos().x() >= scene->sceneRect().right() ||       ellipse->pos().x() <= scene->sceneRect().left()){ 
        movement_x = -movement_x;
     }
    if(ellipse->pos().y() >= scene->sceneRect().bottom() ||     ellipse->pos().y() <= scene->sceneRect().top()){
        movement_y = -movement_y;
     }
    ellipse->moveBy(movement_x, movement_y);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QGraphicsScene>

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();


protected:
    void showEvent(QShowEvent* event);
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent* event);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse;
 };

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.resize(800,600);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I suggest to have a look here for an easier way to run animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value of pos is `(0,0)`. Because of this your update oscillate between two values. After `addEllipse` you have to set an initial position within the scene rect. For example

```
ellipse->setPos(100,100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should map the ellipse position from the scene to find the boundaries :

```
QPoint posOfEclps = ellipse->mapToScene(ellipse->pos());


if(posOfEclps.x() >= scene->sceneRect().right() || posOfEclps.x() <= scene->sceneRect().left())
{ 
    movement_x = -movement_x;
}
if(posOfEclps.y() >= scene->sceneRect().bottom() || posOfEclps.y() <= scene->sceneRect().top())
{
    movement_y = -movement_y;
}
ellipse->moveBy(movement_x, movement_y);
```